# Use the Inverse Function Theorem to show that this parametrisation has a continuous inverse.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

Consider the parametrisation of $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}$ given by $F$, where $F(x,y)=(\frac{2x}{1+r^2},\frac{2y}{1+r^2},\frac{r^2-1}{r^2+1})$ with $r^2=x^2+y^2$. The parameter set is $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$.

I want to show that $F$ has a continuous inverse by the *Inverse Function Theorem*. Although I am having difficulty seeing how exactly I should apply it.

We recall that the Inverse Function Theorem states that:

*"If $F$ is a continuously differentiable function from an open set of $\mathbb R^n$ into $\mathbb R^n$, and the total derivative is invertible at a point $p$ (i.e. the Jacobian determinant of $F$ at $p$ is non-zero) then $F$ is invertible near $p$."*

It's not hard to see that $F$ is $C^\infty$ by noting that each of its components are $C^\infty$. But in order to apply the Inverse Function Theorem $F$ would need to be a map of the form from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ so as **to be able** to actually determine the Jacobian determinant. However, $F:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$, and so we cannot  form the Jacobian determinant. How, then, am I to apply to Inverse Function Theorem to see that $F^{-1}$ is also $C^\infty$?

Comment: There must be a typo in the definition of $F$.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am working back from the solutions I have available in which it is stated that by using IFT we see that $F^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$. But even disregarding that fact, $F$ is the parametrisation of a surface, which by definition means that it is a map from an open region of $\mathbb R^2$ to an open region of $\mathbb R^3$, so I don't think there is a mistake in the definition of $F$. Unless you perhaps don't use IFT to deduce this fact ... (?)

Comment: Shouldn’t be the norm of $F$ constant?

Comment: I think yes, since $F$ parametrises part of a sphere. But how would you use this fact to deduce that $F$ has a continuous inverse?

Comment: I guess $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: I think we can determine the matrix of partial derivatives which is 2 by 3 and see if it has maximal rank (i.e 2) at each point.

Comment: The third coordinate is constant, how could this be a sphere?  Also the norm of $F$ isn't constant ...

Comment: @MaikPickl Indeed, that works.